# Regular expression replace in Textpad where search term spans multiple lines

Tags: regex, textpad

Is it possible to do a regular expression search and replace in Textpad where the search term spans multiple lines.

e.g. document contains:

```
Hello
ab_c
D_EF
12_3
World
```

I would like to replace everything between "Hello" and "World" with a space.

I have tried searching for the regular expression:

```
Hello.*World
```

but this does not match (I assume due to the text spanning across multiple lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Textpad seems to have only very limited regex support, I only got it done with three replaces:

1. Replace each newline (`\n` or `\r\n`) in your text with a unique pattern, e.g. `##NEWLINE##`
2. Use the regex `(Hello).*(World)` and replace the match with `\1 \2`
   (you can also just use `Hello.*World` and replace with `Hello World`)
3. Finally, revert step 1 by replacing all `##NEWLINE##` with the actual newline

---

I suggest taking a look on [Notepad++](http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org/) which has better regex support, a lot of other features (especially for source code editing), and is open source / free software.